# Finding gas leak from gas pipeline

Tags: natural-gas, gasleak, pipeline

I live in 3rd floor condominium in New Jersey, last week we found a gas leak somewhere in my pipeline.

Plumber from home owner association disconnected gas pipeline from the meter and installed meter to pressure test the line with air. He also disconnected all appliances and put an end-cap on pipelines. Then he gave me big estimate to find the leak and fix it. Association gave me option to choose my own plumber to find the leak and have it fixed.

My question is, As a home owner (I don't have any license), can I find that leak in now dead pipeline myself? If leak is in one of the joints inside my walls, it would be easy for me and cheaper to point the leak to plumber to save some money.

I can hook up compressor to the line, build up required pressure and check if the leak is within my walls by spraying soap water on joints and look out for bubbles.

Gas line is dead, disconnected from the utility company meter.

Comment: You can.  The problem is if the leak is inside of walls/hidden.  I think you want to keep the pressure low below twenty pounds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, as long as the condo association doesn't have a problem with it.  Since they are not paying for it, they don't have much of a case to tell you not to. You explained the way to do it.  Just be careful about how much pressure you put in the pipe.  I usually use 10-15PSI.  YMMV with old pipe.  I wouldn't go much higher.  The difficulty is finding the leak behind the leak behind walls.  If you could isolate sections of the pipe and put a pressure gauge on that section, that may help you narrow down the location, but to be honest, that job is going to suck without ripping the walls out.  This is probably why the plumber is charging so much.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, As a home owner (I don't have any license), can I find that leak in now dead pipeline myself?

You're in a condo, read the contract you signed. Since you're not licensed, it is likely illegal for you to modify the gas infrastructure of something which could kill more than just you.

Even if you find the leak, you'll need a plumber or code enforcer to sign off on the plumbing work.

> I can hook up compressor to the line

Residential gas is usually 1/4" PSI, a compressor is overkill. Get a manual bike tire pump and a gauge with a schrader valve. 10-20 PSI max.

If the leak is large enough that a bike pump cannot keep up with it then use the compressor and listen for audible hissing.

> build up required pressure and check if the leak is within my walls by spraying soap water on joints and look out for bubbles

Hopefully the leak is not in your walls.